# Solr only search in default field

Tags: solr

I can't search in other field than the default. With q=field:search doesn't return nothing (but documents exists obsviouly). Also didn't find it with defType=dismax.

In the schema.xml I have the field with indexed="true" and stored="true" just like the default one.

What I am missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you are issuing a GET? 
Have you checked your encoding the ':', as it should be %3A.
Without the right encoding you maybe trying to search the default field for 'field:search'.

Can you test your query in /solr/admin ?

Comment: Yes, I'm issuing GET and the enconding are correct. 

It seems that is my query to the database: The query for import data are from two diferent tables: select table1.*, table2.field_title as title_table2 ... 

and are this "title_table2" that I can search in (it's configured in data-config.xml and schema.xml correctly). 

Is there another way of doing this type of querys ? It should be two entity anidates in data-config?

Answer (score 0):

just checking, if you changed your schema, you need to delete the data in /var/data and restart solr, otherwise you may be searching old not indexed stuff.

Comment: I have tried to delete the data dir, full import again and doesn't work either: still doesn't find anything in "sub-entitys" fields, but this fields shows when search in fields of the "main-entity"

Comment: can you try something like the schema I gave in answer in the following and see if it works there ?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948587/retrieving-extracted-text-with-apache-solr/4959103#4959103

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DisMax search make sure that you have the fields you are searching added to the [query fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) parameter solr search. It might just be that you are declaring a `qf` parameter in your search statement and your field is missing from the list.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit too plain, but did you - besides restarting your solr instance - remember reindex? Otherwise changes in the `schema.xml` won't apply.