# SOLR: Get Full Text Content for document that matches query

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I have a SOLR instance and wish to extract out the full text content that was indexed within the instance. Is this possible?

If there is a query type I can use to fetch the full text content from the instance, I'd be grateful if someone could point me to it!

Comment: this seems promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948587/retrieving-extracted-text-with-apache-solr

Comment: Are you indexing documents (like PDF, docx, etc.), or how are you getting data into Solr? If you're submitting it yourself, the only requirements is that the field is set as `stored="true"` and that you're including it in the field list when retrieving documents (the `fl` parameter).

Comment: ha, I just learned that! My schema had `stored="false"` so I think this content is not retrievable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the SOLR schema must specify `stored="true"` on the field that stores the full text in order for a query to fetch all of the content in that field.

My schema specified the opposite, which means that this text is lot retrievable (though it is searchable, as the schema specifies `index="true"`!

Comment: Quick question. When you say stored="false" where does the data go? Is it searchable at all? attached to the document? or only if you have indexed="true" on the field?

Comment: Check out these docs: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/defining-fields.html. In a nutshell, stored=false and index=true won't store the raw text content for e.g. display purposes, it just builds the index for e.g. search purposes. So stored=false would be useful if you just want to know the document ids that contain "rabbit in hat" for example. I'm not sure why one would use stored=false _and_ index=false